# How to make multiple calculation in excel based on multiple criteria?

Tags: excel

trying to make excel to perform a calculation based on the "market"(K) column, each market has a different fee percentage. Ex.if column K says Amazon it should multiply by 9%, if it says bigcommerce 8%, if shop.com 7%. 
What I'm looking for is like this...If K9 (market) = "amazon us" then G9 (sales price) - F9 (carrier fee) - D9 (INSURANCE) - L9 (Cost) - G9*0.09 (That will be the percentage charged by amazon).

Any idea will help!
Thank you!

[image: Orders table, each row is a different order]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Build a lookup table for the Fee Percentages:

```
Amazon US   0.09
BigCommerce 0.08
Shop.Com    0.07
```

So if this table is in Sheet2 cells A1:B3, the formula to get the fee will be:

```
-G9*vlookup(K9,Sheet2!$A$1:$B$3,2,0)
```

And your entire formula will be:

```
=G9-F9-D9-L9-(G9*vlookup(K9,Sheet2!$A$1:$B$3,2,0)
```

Then you can drag down the rows.

For more on [VLOOKUP](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/VLOOKUP-function-0BBC8083-26FE-4963-8AB8-93A18AD188A1)

Comment: Yeap! that will do it, thanks!...but just out of curiosity, is there any way to do it without the need to add an extra table with the percentages?

Comment: @DHI technically yes, but a formula with a "built in lookup table" gets very long and unwieldy very quickly.  Scott's answer here is the best practice solution.

Comment: @DHi - yes, you could write a bunch of IF statements in place of the `vlookup`, but you can see how quickly that can get unwieldy. Maybe with only 3 options it's not *so* bad, but once you add more, it gets nastier and nastier. The lookup table keeps everything clean and easily updateable.